# How i can define parameter in omnet++ that will use other parameter definition?

Tags: omnet++

This is the ini file definition that I have:

```
[General]
network = AQM
**.Nodes = 100  # Numer of Nodes
**.Qmax = 1000  # Buffer Size
**.Qref = 0.25*par("Qmax")
```

I want that Qref will be 0.25 of the Qmax.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can name variables and use them afterwards:

```
[General]
network = AQM
**.Nodes = ${cnt=100} # Numer of Nodes
**.Qmax = 1000 # Buffer Size
**.Qref = 0.25*${cnt}
```

This even works with ranges or lists:

```
**.var1 = ${i=0..1 step 0.2}
**.var2 = ${i} * 0.01
```